# .htaccess something wrong with code

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^groups/([0-9+]*)/(.*)$ /users.php?group=$1 [QSA,L,E]
```

www.mysite.com/groups/11/all-users

in users.php i try get group id:
echo $_GET['group'];

Why always get "false"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I heartily recommend using the RewriteLog functionality for debugging your rewrite rules, I find it helps immensely to demystify what's happening inside.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

From what I can tell, you're merely missing the leading slash in the URL. I tested locally using (note the added leading slash before groups):

```
RewriteRule ^/groups/([0-9+]*)/(.*)$ /users.php?group=$1 [QSA,L,E]
```

The resulting page does a vardump of $_GET, providing:

```
array(1) { ["group"]=> string(2) "11" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Example:

```
The original URL: http://www.mysite.com/users.php?group=1

The rewritten URL: http://www.mysite.com/group/1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]*)$ /users.php?group=$1 [L]
```